# Python IMAP proxy connection

Tags: python, python-3.x, imap, socks, imaplib

I tried to login to IMAP5 server through a SOCKS5 proxy using python 3.5, but it doesn't login and shows this error:
command: LOGIN => Autologout internal error, we will remember you as ffcd2fca-96a9-4c64-89d5-361123783232

If i am not using proxy, then everything is ok.

I have some questions

**1.Is it because of the proxy server and it forbids IMAP4 connection?**

**2.How can I solve that?**

```
import ssl, time

from socks import create_connection
from socks import PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS4
from socks import PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5
from socks import PROXY_TYPE_HTTP

from imaplib import IMAP4
from imaplib import IMAP4_PORT
from imaplib import IMAP4_SSL_PORT
from filter import get_user_pass

__author__ = "sstevan"
__license__ = "GPLv3"
__version__ = "0.1"


class SocksIMAP4(IMAP4):
    """
    IMAP service trough SOCKS proxy. PySocks module required.
    """

    PROXY_TYPES = {"socks4": PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS4,
                   "socks5": PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5,
                   "http": PROXY_TYPE_HTTP}

    def __init__(self, host, port=IMAP4_PORT, proxy_addr=None, proxy_port=None,
                 rdns=True, username=None, password=None, proxy_type="socks5"):

        self.proxy_addr = proxy_addr
        self.proxy_port = proxy_port
        self.rdns = rdns
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.proxy_type = SocksIMAP4.PROXY_TYPES[proxy_type.lower()]

        IMAP4.__init__(self, host, port)

    def _create_socket(self):
        return create_connection((self.host, self.port), proxy_type=self.proxy_type, proxy_addr=self.proxy_addr,
                                 proxy_port=self.proxy_port, proxy_rdns=self.rdns, proxy_username=self.username,
                                 proxy_password=self.password)


class SocksIMAP4SSL(SocksIMAP4):

    def __init__(self, host='', port=IMAP4_SSL_PORT, keyfile=None, certfile=None, ssl_context=None, proxy_addr=None,
                 proxy_port=None, rdns=True, username=None, password=None, proxy_type="socks5"):

        if ssl_context is not None and keyfile is not None:
                raise ValueError("ssl_context and keyfile arguments are mutually "
                                 "exclusive")
        if ssl_context is not None and certfile is not None:
            raise ValueError("ssl_context and certfile arguments are mutually "
                             "exclusive")

        self.keyfile = keyfile
        self.certfile = certfile
        if ssl_context is None:
            ssl_context = ssl._create_stdlib_context(certfile=certfile,
                                                     keyfile=keyfile)
        self.ssl_context = ssl_context

        SocksIMAP4.__init__(self, host, port, proxy_addr=proxy_addr, proxy_port=proxy_port,
                            rdns=rdns, username=username, password=password, proxy_type=proxy_type)

    def _create_socket(self):
        sock = SocksIMAP4._create_socket(self)
        server_hostname = self.host if ssl.HAS_SNI else None
        return self.ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)

    def open(self, host='', port=IMAP4_PORT):
        SocksIMAP4.open(self, host, port)

def connect_proxy(imap_server, imap_port, proxy_addr, proxy_port, proxy_type, email, password):
    mailbox = SocksIMAP4SSL(host=imap_server, port=imap_port,
                            proxy_addr=proxy_addr, proxy_port=proxy_port, proxy_type=proxy_type)
    try:
        mailbox.login(email, password)
        print("We are here")
        print("OK ",)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return False
    print(mailbox.state)
    mailbox.logout()
    return True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    imap_server = "imap.rambler.ru"
    imap_port = 993

    proxy_addr = "188.120.224.172"
    proxy_port = 59923
    proxy_type = "socks5"
    email, password = get_user_pass("pm@mail11.rambler.ru:11")
    if email is not None:
        resp = connect_proxy(imap_server, imap_port, proxy_addr, proxy_port, proxy_type, email, password)
        #resp = connect(email, password, "smtp.rambler.ru")
    time.sleep(1)
```

**EMAIL:PASSWORD pair is for test. Don't steal it:)**

Comment: Try setting IMAP4.debug to >= 3 to get a protocol trace, to see what it's sending and receiving, or imaplib.Debug to turn it on by default for all instances.

Comment: 43:36.98 > b'KBLN1 LOGIN pm@mail11.rambler.ru "11"'                                                                                                     
 43:41.49 < b'* BYE Autologout internal error, we will remember you as e3cc2f00-ad7b-4316-a74a-c8a8f03e9d04'
 43:41.49 BYE response: b'Autologout internal error, we will remember you as e3cc2f00-ad7b-4316-a74a-c8a8f03e9d04'                                      What does this mean?

Comment: Do you see the OK login line before that?  That is very odd.  You seem to be tickling some sort of bug in the server, but I don't understand how.

Comment: NO, Do I have tp report this? And how to enable debug on imaplib, not on that class?

Comment: @CaucasianLaughts f you have found an answer, I recommend you to publish it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood it was either Rambler's bug or a tiny feature to prevent some malicious users, like I am, from brute forcing accounts.

If anyone would ever see this thread and have some solutions, ideas or such problem, feel free to contact me.

Comment: ahh, was just trying to use it to send some truth to random russian email addresses